# selecting last record from table

Tags: c#, sql, database, oledb

I am deveoping a c# app in which oledb connection is used.

My table is following

payment

```
Id   RemFee
1     2000
2     2500
1     1500
3     8000
3     5000
2      500
3        0
```

I want to select and check only last record of each Id and compare Remfee to 0. If it is greater than 0 then print the record. i.e. My expected result is:

```
Id  
1    
2
```

In this check is made for Id 1 with RemFee 1500 (as it is last record with Id1). It is grater than 0 hence record is printed.

Comment: There is no inherent order inside an SQL table, you should use a column to store the order so you know wich was your last inserted row. As for what you have how we should know the last inserted row has an `Id` of 1 or 2. Also, wich RDBMS are you using, MS SQL Server, Oracle, MySQL?

Comment: this will somewhat fail, you need to add atleast a column that will point out the latest record for each ID.

Comment: @freelancer what do you mean with last record? The last one inserted? How do you maintain insertion order in this table structure?

Comment: last record of each id.i.e. last record with Id 1 is 1500 Id 2 is 500 and so on

Comment: Yeah it is easy to say just by looking at the table on the screen. But the sql engine does not operate that way. It does not differentiate these records in terms of **order**

Comment: I tried the query with Last(Id) and something but it does not work

Comment: @freelancer, there is no `LAST` clause to know wich was your last inserted row. As already commented, there is no inherent order on the rows you insert, you need an additional column to set that order. Say a daytime column for example, with a default value of `GETDATE()`. Other alternative is to use an index, [check here](http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1337/building-sql-server-indexes-in-ascending-vs-descending-order/) for a detailed example

Comment: yeah. I came to now this fact after using 'last' in my query

Comment: @freelancer you should have mentioned that field remfee is an always decreasing value by each id on every record insertion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Guessing you are using MSQ SQL Server and no row to know wich is your last inserted row. Try this code:

```
SELECT Id, Min(RemFee) AS RemFee
  FROM payment
 WHERE RemFee > 0
 GROUP BY ID
```

Here is an **[SQL Fiddle working](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/a6fab/5)** code sample

**EDIT**

If you only want the ID field here is one option, together with the **[SQL Fiddle code](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/a6fab/11)**

```
SELECT myTable.Id
  FROM (SELECT Id as ID, Min(RemFee) AS Remfee
          FROM payment
         WHERE RemFee > 0
         GROUP BY ID
        ) myTable
```

Comment: what if i want only id as a result with same conditions?

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT ID,MIN(REMFEE) FROM payment WHERE ID NOT IN (SELECT ID FROM  payment  WHERE REMFEE  = 0) GROUP BY ID
```

Comment: what if i want to print only id?

Answer (score 0):

```
Select 
   id, Min(RemFee) 
from payment 
where RemFee > 0 
group by id
```